# how do i seperate usage of network for file sharing and internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop

In my office, I have two laptops (using internet with build in wireless)  and a destop computer (using interent with external wireless adapter).
The problem is file sharing between these three. If i use the wireless for file sharing, it takes more than one minute and 30 sec to transfer nearly 4 MB folder. So, it is time coumsing when we need to transfer more bigger file size. I also have a switch to connect a physical network. So, i connect them. But still it is not ok. The computers are still using wireless for both file and printer sharing and internet. **Is there anyway to command them to used physical network for file sharing and wireless for internet?**

If you have solutions please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Which OS are your computers using?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable the network adapter for your wireless connection.
In Windows 7, you can find this at Control panel --> Network and Internet --> Network and sharing center.
On the left you should see an option like 'Change adapter settings', go there.
Select the adapter for your wireless connection and click 'Disable this network device'.

I just told you for Window 7 OS, for others I don't know from the top of my head.
Any way, for any OS you should be able to disable the wireless adapter.

Just an extra note:
4MB doesn't tell you everything about the 'size'. If there are 10000 files in that folder, it will take more time. One big file is always easier to copy then multiple small files.